# automatically restart firefox with bash script when not running

Tags: bash, ubuntu, xdotool

I'm working on a kiosk application where I use Firefox, and want to ensure that it restart in full screen if it would crash

The code works well without the xdotool line like this

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
if [ ! `pgrep firefox-bin` ];then
firefox -url http://localhost   
fi
sleep 5
done
```

but if I add the xdotool line for fullscreen, it will keep opening firefox every 5 seconds

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
if [ ! `pgrep firefox-bin` ];then
firefox -url http://localhost &
xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class "Firefox" windowactivate key F11 
fi
sleep 5
done
```

Where is the error in my script? 
Thanks

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: On a guess, because you are running firefox as a background process, `xdotool` may be executing too soon.  A `sleep` before the `xdotool` call may work as a dirty fix.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem